# Choosing a random color from an array of colors to use in a View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

How can I chose a random color from an array of colors when iterating on an array of names so each name will have a diffrent text foreground color ?

```
struct TextRow: View {
var names : [String]
var color: [Color]
var body: some View {
      HStack{
         
           ForEach(names, id: \.self){
           item in
                
               Text(item)
           }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply shuffle the colors array and then iterate on the names index

Example:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var names : [String] = ["1", "2" ,"3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    var colors: [Color] = [.red, .gray, .green, .yellow, .blue].shuffled()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ForEach(Array(names.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
                Text(element)
                    .background(colors[safe: index] ?? colors[safe: index - colors.count])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added the safe collection extension in case names and colors have a different count

Answer (score 2):

This did the job for me:

```
// ... omitted

var body: some View {
        let colors: [Color] = [.green, .red, .primaryColor, .orange, .blue, .gray]
        
        ScrollView {
Image(systemName: name.prefix(1).lowercased() + ".circle.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                .foregroundColor(colors.randomElement())
}
/// ... omitted**strong text**
```